# Affinity Designer: How to edit selected path with the pen tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, affinity-designer, pencil

There's a pencil option in Adobe Illustrator that allows you to correct the initial path. For instances, let's say I'm drawing hair in a flat illustration and I would like to give the hair more volume by using the pencil tool and adding to it lines.

**I would like to know where to find this option or equivalent in Affinity Designer.**

In the pictures below for instances, instead of simply drawing the stoke with a filled path and being an independent path, I would like the path drawn with the pencil to add up to the original one. Now, when I select the hair, I'll be only selecting one path and not the original + pencil paths.

I am aware I can achieve this by editing the original path with the node tool. However, I find this option more time consuming and would like to know a faster alternative. I am also aware of the sculpting tool. Although it is close, I would still like to know if there's a better alternative.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node tool can be set temporarily ON by pressing Ctrl when you are drawing with the pen or pencil. Select the unwanted or misplaced node. Move it or press DEL to evaporate it without breaking the path.

Continue your drawing. Click with the pen or pencil the end node of the current result to continue the drawing of the path.

You can add a jut to another path by selecting both and applying Boolean ADD. Both paths can be open or closed. Example:

[image]

The green open path B can be inserted to A by selecting A and B and applying path combining function Add. The result is a closed curve.

A has got an extra segment. That doesn't happen if A is already a closed curve.

If the extra segment is not wanted you must break A and DEL the extra segment.

NOTE: A and B had originally 2 crossings.